# Using a 4-pin jack Headset on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, laptop, headset, audio-jack

I have a laptop on Ubuntu 16.04 and I can't use the microphone from my 4-pin jack headset. Here is what I get when I run `lshw -c sound` in the terminal (translated from French):

```
  *-multimedia:0          
   description: Audio device
   product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:52 memory:c4510000-c4513fff
  *-usb:4
   description: Video
   product: HD WebCam
   vendor: NC2141103M514060B1LM05
   physical id: 7
   bus info: usb@2:7
   version: 0.05
   capabilities: usb-2.00
   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia:1
   description: Audio device
   product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
   resources: irq:51 memory:c4514000-c4517fff
```

Does someone know how can I switch Pulse microphone on my headset and not on the laptop's one please ?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens They are asking how to get PulseAudio to recognize the microphone on their headset (plugged into a 4-pin jack) instead of using the laptop's built-in mic.

Comment: @Florian_PB Is the jack on your computer capable of handling a 4-pin combination mic/headset? Have you gotten it working under other operating systems on the same machine? I'm wondering if it's a hardware issue. If so, you can buy an inexpensive splitter that turns the 4-pin combination jack into separate headphone and microphone jacks (e.g. https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-MUYHSFMM-Headset-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B0058DOWH6 )

Comment: @NickWeinberg yes my jack is capable of handling a 4-pin combination mic/headset on Windows 7 and 10, and I have only the 4-pin jack on my laptop so I can't use a splitter

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens The question was awkwardly-worded, yet still pretty clear to me. Clear interpersonal communication is still one of humanity's greatest challenges; but now that we all understand each other, let's move on.

Comment: I have Asus R540L on Ubuntu 16.04 and having exactly same issues. My jack port can only be used with the headphones, does not detect the mic, even though the 4-pin splitter is used.